# Get data from XML document using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I would like to get datas from a specific XML format. The XML document looks like that:

```
<MyXML>
<Sources> 
     <S1>www.example1.org</S1>
     <S2>www.example2.org</S2>
</Sources>
<Books>
    <Book id="1">
        <Datas>
            <Data name="Book_1_Name" tag="1111" />
            <Data name="Book_2_Name" tag="2222" />
        </Datas>
    </Book >
    <Book id="2">
        <Datas>
            <Data name="Book_1_Name" tag="3333" />
            <Data name="Book_2_Name" tag="4444" />
        </Datas>
    </Book >
</Books>
```

My question is:
How can I get *www.example1.org* if I know S1?
How can I search "*Book_1_name*" from Book id=1?

I am using C# with XDocument like this:

```
XDocument.Load(_XML_path);
var node = _configXml.XPathSelectElement("MyXML/Books/Datas");
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956494/reading-specific-xml-parameter

Comment: or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading specific XML parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956494/reading-specific-xml-parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `XPath`, About `XPath` see this : http://www.xfront.com/xpath/

```
var _configXml = XDocument.Load(_XML_path);
//how to get S1 element.
var s1 = _configXml.XPathSelectElement("MyXML/Sources/S1");
//how search
var search = _configXml.XPathSelectElements("//Book[@id='1']//Data[@name='Book_1_Name']");
Console.WriteLine(s1.Value);
Console.WriteLine(search.First().Attribute("tag").Value);
```

Comment: This is obviously the more `XDocument`-like way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should map the XML to a C# object. Then, you can use the following to get what you want:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyXML));
var xml = (MyXML)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(XDocument.Load(_XML_path)));
var s1 = xml.Sources.S1;
```

Answer (score 0):

*If* you want to stick with a `XDocument`, you can do the following

```
var books = doc.Element("MyXML").Element("Books");
var bookById = books.Elements("Book")
                    .Where(b => b.Attribute("id").Value == "1")
                    .Select(b => b.Element("Datas"));
```

In the first line, you are selecting the `Books` node (please note, in a real-world scenario, I'd add some checks here). In the following line you are first getting all `Book` sub-elements (`books.Elements("Book")`), checking them for the ID you are searching for (`Where(b => b.Attribute("id").Value == "1")`) and then select the data node from the respective book. You could re-write this to query syntax

```
var bookById = from book in books.Elements("Book")
               let id = book.Attribute("id")
               let datas = book.Element("Datas")
               where id != null
                    && datas != null
                    && id.Value == "1"
               select datas;
```

which is a bit longer, but easier to read.

Comment: *Or* you could use `XPathSelectElement` (`var books = doc.XPathSelectElement("MyXML/Books")`) to get the "Books" node.