# How to read values from xml and store it in hash map in java

Tags: java, xml, hashmap

```
    I am new to xml parsing.I have to retrieve these particular fields (USERNAME,PASSWORD) and needs to save in a hashmap in java
```

---

.

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<REQUEST version="10">
<AUTHENTICATION>
<USERNAME>ABC</USERNAME>
<PASSWORD>123</PASSWORD>
</AUTHENTICATION>
<DATA>
<ADDRESS>add1</ADDRESS>
</DATA>
</REQUEST>
```

Could anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/xml-json-hashmap - check this url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check this for reading specific parameters from xml file:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956494/reading-specific-xml-parameter)

But there is a better way for handling xml files. Since you didn't provide any more details, I'm going to post one way of reading data from xml file.

Easiest way is to define a type that represents data that is in your xml file. Then you can easily read and write that data into the xml file.

For example you define type Person:

```
public class Person{
   private String username="";
   private String password="";
   private String address="";

   // Constructor(s), getters, setters...
}
```

And when you want to save data into the xml, just serialize Person object:

```
public boolean serialize(Person p, String path) {
        try {
            XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(new FileOutputStream(new File(path+File.separator+p.getUsername()+".xml")));
            encoder.writeObject(s);
            encoder.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Now when you want to read from xml file, just deserialize it into Person object:

```
public Person deserialization(String name, String path) {
        Person p=null;
        try {
            XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(new FileInputStream(new File(path+File.separator+name+".xml")));
            p=(Person) decoder.readObject();
            decoder.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return p;
    }
```

And finally you can store it easier in HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, String> hash_map = new HashMap<String, String>();
hash_map.put(p.getUsername(),p.getPassword());  // p is a Person object
```

NOTE: This is just one way of doing it, you can adjust it to your needs. You should take care of the file path that you provide (if you use xml files from some server maybe approach is different, this example reffers to using xml files from local file system).
Also note that passwords should be protected, encrypted for example.